# what does "politicians are still politicians, but in Scandinavia they are perhaps more principled"

Tags: word-meaning

> politicians are still politicians, but in Scandinavia they are perhaps more principled

What does this mean?

Comment: Which part of the sentence you don't understand?

Comment: the whole sent.

Comment: Politicians outside Scandinavia are *less* principled.

Answer (score 4):

> politicians are still politicians, but in Scandinavia they are perhaps more principled

1. **Politicians are still politicians:** Politicians all over the world are known for being prone to corruption, self-advancement, loud but empty promises, scandals, opportunism, unwillingness to risk their career through decisive action. Scandinavia is no exception. So, despite being in Scandinavia, they are "**still** (continue to be typical) **politicians**", just like we know them.
2. However, according to the author, in Scandinavia politicians for some reason exhibit some qualities that make them stand out compared with politicians in other countries. Trying to explain this peculiarity to his readers, the author writes "**but in Scandinavia they are perhaps more principled**". He is not completely sure whether they are indeed more principled, but merely tries to relate his impression.